# Dress: hem or bottom

Tags: vocabulary

What do we call the lowest edge of pants? Bottoms or hems?

> ```
>   The bottoms of her pants are above her ankles.
>     
>   The hems of her pants are above her ankles.
> ```

Which of the two fits best for the picture?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"Hem" is a good word to use for the sewn finish of pants.  Bottom could (perhaps) refer to the gusset.

> Parents might have to adjust the hem of their children's pants as they grow older.

However, as noted in comments, these trousers are actually unhemmed; there is no sewn neat finish at the her ankles. Instead you could say

> Her pants have been cut short above her ankles.

(although I'd say "trousers", because {snigger})

Comment: I'd disagree on hem. A hem is "a border of a cloth article doubled back and stitched down" ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hem)), for example,  [something like this](https://img.babylock.com/6c9c98ea-31d4-4f70-95a4-e2ae38ae7412.jpeg). Whereas these jeans are unhemmed.